# How can I use Fragments without violating core OO principles?

Tags: android, oop, android-fragments, android-view

The documented Android fragment samples ([FragmentBasics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html), [NewsReader](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html) violate core principles of object oriented design.  There are redundant conditionals to establish the currently showing view type, tightly coupling the `FragmentActivity` with the view types and fragment types.  `MainActivity` is coupled to every class (including the XML):

[image]

One might be able to make the excuse for the authors that they are trying to "keep it simple," or that readers might be confused.  If this is the intent--I think readers can handle it; instead, it's teaching bad programming practices that will result in less maintainable applications.

How can `Fragments` be implemented such that the views and fragments aren't tightly coupled to the `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Jeff.  I'm confused. What is the purpose of posing a question then immediately answering it?

Comment: Ah, got it.  Thanks, learn something every day (usually with a visit here).  I love the answer BTW so an up from me.

Comment: +1 for helping me see that I am not alone in my confusion over some practices in the Android universe. I still don't understand why the Android framework allows passing `Activity` around (as seen in in the [stock browser](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/browser/Tab.java?av=f#446)).

Comment: @BillTheApe this is totally off topic and we should probably start a new question about this or chat, but I don't follow why `Activity` shouldn't be allowed to be passed around, let alone how it could be prevented.  I do this all the time and I'm not sure how one would write OO Android code without this ability.  I assume your problem with it is potential memory leaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with the simpler [FragmentBasics](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) demo, gut `MainActivity` as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
      implements OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
   AbstractNewsView abstractNewsView;

   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);
      abstractNewsView = new AbstractNewsViewProvider(this).get();
      abstractNewsView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }

   @Override public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
      abstractNewsView.onArticleSelected(position);
   }
}
```

Now its dependency diagram looks like this.  You can now add all the `news_articles` view variants you'd like for different device types and `MainActivity` doesn't need to change.

[image]

Add a new class `AbstractNewsViewProvider` whose sole responsibility is to determine which type of view (single or double pane) is being used for the given device.  If you're using Guice or RoboGuice for dependency injection, this would instead be a [Provider](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods) method in your binding module.

```
public class AbstractNewsViewProvider {
   private final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

   public AbstractNewsViewProvider(FragmentActivity activity) {
      this.fragmentActivity = activity;
   }

   public AbstractNewsView get() {
      if (fragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
           return new SinglePaneNewsView(fragmentActivity);
        } else {
           return new DoublePaneNewsView(fragmentActivity);
        }
   }
}
```

Add two new classes `SinglePaneNewsView` and `DoublePaneNewsView` that implement `AbstractNewsView` as shown below.  These two classes are responsible for the setup of the initial fragment(s) within the respective view type.  They are also responsible for handling transitions between fragments, if any.

```
interface AbstractNewsView extends OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);
   @Override public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}


public class SinglePaneNewsView implements AbstractNewsView {

   private final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

   public SinglePaneNewsView(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
      this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
   }

   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
      // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
      // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
      if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         return;
      }

      // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
      HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

      // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
      // Intent,
      // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
      firstFragment.setArguments(fragmentActivity.getIntent().getExtras());

      // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
      fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
   }

   @Override public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
      // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must
      // swap frags...

      // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
      ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
      Bundle args = new Bundle();
      args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
      newFragment.setArguments(args);
      FragmentTransaction transaction =
            fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

      // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
      // Add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
      transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
      transaction.addToBackStack(null);

      // Commit the transaction
      transaction.commit();
   }


public class DoublePaneNewsView implements AbstractNewsView {

   private final FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

   public DoublePaneNewsView(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
      this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
   }

   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   }

   @Override public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
      ((ArticleFragment) fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
         .findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment)).updateArticleView(position);
   }

}
```

You can find the [complete source](http://code.google.com/p/android-oo-fragment-example/) on Google code.